# Figure.transFigure.transform() : lines in figure coordinates do not scale with the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw lines in figure coordinates using the `Figure.transFigure.transform()` functionality, but either I don't fully understand it or something else goes wrong. According to the [Matplotlib Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/transforms_tutorial.html), `transFigure` should be

> The coordinate system of the Figure; (0,0) is bottom left of the
>   figure, and (1,1) is top right of the figure.

However, if I write a small test program that should draw a diagonal line from the bottom left to the top right corner of the `Figure` (not the `Axes`), this only draws the line correctly in the original figure. Once the figure is resized, the line does not anymore end in the upper right corner. Below a small test program to illustrate this behaviour:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import lines
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)

X = np.array([0.0,1.0])
Y = np.array([0.0,1.0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, np.cos(x))
X0, Y0 = fig.transFigure.transform([X,Y])

line1 = lines.Line2D(X0, Y0, color='r', lw = 5)
fig.lines.append(line1)

plt.show()
```

...and the resulting figure after an arbitrary resize:

[image: figure that results from the above code after resizing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you create a static line in pixel coordinates here. It will always range from (0,0) to (x1,y1) pixels, where (x1,y1) is the upper right corner of the original figure.

What is usually wanted is to create a line that goes from (0,0) to (1,1) in figure coordinates. So one would not transform the points manually, but let the `fig.transFigure` do the transform, as

```
line1 = lines.Line2D([0,1], [0,1], transform=fig.transFigure)
```

Complete example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import lines
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)

X = np.array([0.0,1.0])
Y = np.array([0.0,1.0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5), dpi = 100)

ax.plot(x, np.cos(x))

line1 = lines.Line2D(X, Y, color='r', lw = 5, transform=fig.transFigure)
fig.lines.append(line1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

This produces the same plot as in the question, but with the advantage that you don't need to do any transform yourself and that you may easily scale or resize it.